# How to add a click event row that can go to next page by id?

Tags: javascript

Here, the coding that I got from the Stack Overflow page. The `window.location` should go to next page by id, but I do not know how to code it.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("employee-click");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) {
                return function() { 
                    var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                    var id = cell.innerHTML;
                    window.location.href = "detail.php";
                };
            };

            currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my html code. Would you help me with this code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Data Biodata</title>

<head>
  <meta name="author" content="Arkaprava majumder" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


      var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "dataBiodata.php", // json datasource
      });

      $("#employee-grid_filter").css("display", "none"); // hiding global search box

      $('.employee-search-input').on('keyup click change', function() {
        var i = $(this).attr('id'); // getting column index
        var v = $(this).val(); // getting search input value
        dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
      });
    });

    function addRowHandlers() {
      var table = document.getElementById("employee-click");
      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler =
          function(row) {
            return function() {
              var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
              var id = cell.innerHTML;

              window.location.href = "detail.php";

            };
          };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    div.container {
      max-width: 980px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    div.header {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 980px;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #f7f7f7;
      color: #333;
    }
    
    .employee-search-input {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body onload="addRowHandlers()">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Data Biodata</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- <center> <button style="right:150"> <a href="Biodata.php">Create New</a></button></center>-->
    <table id="employee-grid" class="display" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="100%" border="1" style="text-align: justify;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>System</th>
          <th>Courses</th>
          <th>SVC No</th>
          <th>Pangkat</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="0" class="employee-search-input"></td>

          <td><input type="text" id="1" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="2" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="3" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="4" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="6" class="employee-search-input"></td>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="employee-click">
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>System</th>
          <th>Courses</th>
          <th>SVC No</th>
          <th>Pangkat</th>
          <th>Name</th>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "id"? somethig like window.location.href = "detail.php?id="+id; ?

Comment: Can you insert your html code too? @adam

Comment: yes, something  like window.location.href = "detail.php?id="+id; ?

Comment: Are you wanting to paginate your DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which `id` you mean for redirecting. But I think you should change your `addRowHandlers` function to this. Obtain and use your mentioned `id` and use it after `alert`.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
  var tbody = $("#employee-click tr"); //document.getElementById("employee-click");
  tbody.each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      alert("hi");;
      // window.location.href = "";
    })
  })
}
```

final code is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTable = $("#employee-grid").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "dataBiodata.php" // json datasource
  });

  $("#employee-grid_filter").css("display", "none"); // hiding global search box

  $(".employee-search-input").on("keyup click change", function() {
    var i = $(this).attr("id"); // getting column index
    var v = $(this).val(); // getting search input value
    dataTable
      .columns(i)
      .search(v)
      .draw();
  });
});

function addRowHandlers() {
  var tbody = $("#employee-click tr"); //document.getElementById("employee-click");
  tbody.each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      alert("hi");;
      // window.location.href = "";
    })
  })
}
```

```css
div.container {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 980px;
}

body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  color: #333;
}

.employee-search-input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Data Biodata</title>

<head>
  <meta name="author" content="Arkaprava majumder" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="addRowHandlers()">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Data Biodata</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- <center> <button style="right:150"> <a href="Biodata.php">Create New</a></button></center>-->
    <table id="employee-grid" class="display" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="100%" border="1" style="text-align: justify;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>System</th>
          <th>Courses</th>
          <th>SVC No</th>
          <th>Pangkat</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="0" class="employee-search-input"></td>

          <td><input type="text" id="1" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="2" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="3" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="4" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="6" class="employee-search-input"></td>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="employee-click">
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>System</th>
          <th>Courses</th>
          <th>SVC No</th>
          <th>Pangkat</th>
          <th>Name</th>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i used that coding but it do not help me at all.

Comment: the problem is when i click on the row in window.location.href = "detail.php" i want it directly go by id to the next page.  how to insert the id in the window.location?

Comment: Use something like `window.location.href = "detail.php/" + id`. Like a string. @adam